# How to send Travis build notification to email list AND committer/author

Tags: travis-ci

According to [these instructions](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/notifications/#how-is-the-build-email-receiver-determinedx):

> If there’s a setting specified, Travis CI only sends an emails to the addresses specified there, rather than to the committer and author.

Is there a way to get an email sent **both** to the committer/author and an additional email list?

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Travis support and it sounds like this is not currently possible:

> from: Dominic Jodoin support@travis-ci.com
>
> date: Sep 14, 2018, 7:47 AM
>
> Thanks for reaching out and I'm sorry for the delay of my reply.
>
> What you describe is unfortunately not possible at this time. The notifications settings in your .travis.yml file will always have precedence. Sorry for the inconvenience.
>
> I've added your feature request to our backlog and added a note to contact if/when this gets prioritized and implemented.
>
> Don't hesitate to reach out again in the future for any other questions or problems you might have with Travis CI. We would be happy to help you further.
>
> Cheers,
>
> -- Dominic.